# Importing C# dll in a VC++ 6.0 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, com, unmanaged

I have two projects. One C# project and one VC++ 6.0 project. I would like to import the C# project's functionalities in the unmanaged project.
I followed [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) guide to create the dll and I imported in the VC++ 6.0 project using:
`#import "..\ManagedDLL\bin\Debug\ManagedDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only`
 
My project is built ok but when I try to run it I receive an exception from the debugger when I try to initialize the COM object using:
 `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);` 
 
The messages I get in the Output are:

> Loaded 'C:\XXXXX.dll' No native symbols in symbol
>   file.
> First-chance exception at 0x75befbae in W7.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0349bde0..
>   First-chance exception at 0x75befbae in W7.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
>  First-chance
>   exception at 0x75befbae in W7.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow]
>   at memory location 0x00000000..
>  First-chance exception at
>   0x75befbae in W7.exe: 0xE0434F4D: 0xe0434f4d.
>  First-chance
>   exception at 0x75befbae in W7.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow]
>   at memory location 0x00000000..
>  First-chance exception at
>   0x75befbae in W7.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory
>   location 0x0349ec60..
>  A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in W7.exe
>   'W7.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or
>   open the PDB file
>  An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in W7.exe

I dont know where to look...I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The managed code is bombing but you don't have a managed debugger available to troubleshoot it.  You are going to need the VS version that was used to create this .NET assembly.  It can debug your VS6 code as well.  This is otherwise a "file not found" kind of exception.